# Debugg mode isn't working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I just made a new Console Aplication project in Visual Studio C++. I changed the setup to see the Console when compile&run ( CTRL + F5 ). 
However, when it comes to running into debugging mode ( F5 ), the program is ending even if i do have breakpoints in several places. 
The red circles turn to white and have an exclamation mark during those 2 seconds while it tries to debugg. 
Anyone knows how to fix it ?

Comment: Does it hit the breakpoints if you launch and debug `F5` (Start debugging option under Debug in menu)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Please make sure that your app is in debug mode(not release mode).

(2) Please enable the options like the following screen shot.

[image]

Reference:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797465/visual-c-debugger-does-not-stop-on-breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can check.

First of all assure that the code where the breakpoint is set is reachable. Put it on the entry point of your application.

There is a possibility that the debug symbols where somehow messed up. Hence, try cleaning/rebuilding the project (you can try to delete the bin/build dirs manually).

You could also check under Build->Configuration Manager whether the "Debug" for solution configuration actually makes your project be executed in Debug mode.